# How to configure Unattended Upgrades to send emails to all users?

Tags: server, email, automation, unattended-upgrades, sendmail

I have a Workstation installed with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I would like to automate the maintenance job every 4 months by sending out an email to all users registered on the machine one week before automatically running `sudo apt update & upgrade` and restarting the computer. I would also like to set up an email template and send out to all users 2 days after the maintenance job is completed and verified. I heard [Unattended-Upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) is a proper tool to achieve this goal. But I couldn't find a solution to send emails to *All Users* registered on the machine with customized content using Unattended Upgrades.

Could you shadow a light on me with suggestions of the easiest steps to achieve my goal?

Thanks!